# Loading RAID Drivers For Windows Servers

Tags: raid, drivers

I noticed many RAID controller manufacturers package their drivers in `.exe` files rather than INF's which is what server 2003/2008 seems to want when you load a driver during setup. How can I get these drivers installed so the OS can see my discs?

Comment: Did you try executing the .exe files?

Comment: What drivers are you referring to?

Comment: The drivers for the RAID controller on the motherboard

Answer (score 0):

The manufacturer will almost universally provide the proper driver file formats for different installation scenarios. Search their support site for the proper download and if you can't find it, contact them. If there are no installation-time drivers, then you've found yourself some hardware that has no business being in a production environment.

The ghetto-fab way of doing it would be to open the .exe installation file up using a tool like 7zip to find the individual files that you want, but that's not particularly enterprisey or supportable.